# Disabling Spring cloud consul when running Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, consul

I like to run my unit test with test spring profile without consul. I'm trying to use `spring.cloud.config.enabled:false` and disabling `EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation for test profile but it doesn't work.

I'm using `spring.cloud.consul 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.
Here is the exception:

> com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   com.ecwid.consul.transport.DefaultHttpTransport.executeRequest(DefaultHttpTransport.java:87)
>     at
>   com.ecwid.consul.transport.DefaultHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(DefaultHttpTransport.java:46)
>     at
>   com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:66)

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't real helpful. What error do you get? What version are you using?

Comment: Where did you set `spring.cloud.config.enabled:false` and how did you disable `EnableDiscoveryClient`? The full exception would be helpful to see if it came from discovery or config.

Answer (score 18):

Try disabling Consul with `spring.cloud.consul.enabled:false` in your profile.

I use `@IntegrationTest({"spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false"})` tag to disable consul for my tests, as a class tag. I found that on the Spring Cloud Consul GitHub issue tracker, [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/104).

The other suggestion from that post was to use something like the following as your `bootstrap.yml`.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <myServiceName>
  cloud:
    bus:
      enabled: false
    discovery:
      enabled: false
    consul:
      enabled: false
      config:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, once you put spring-cloud-starter-consul-config, you can't really disable it when you try to import it. So my workaround is just import the consul regardless and then use "optional" so it won't throw error.

```yaml
# will import regardless, but it's okay as "optional" won't throw error
spring.config.import: "optional:consul:"


spring.cloud.consul:
  host: ${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}
  port: ${CONSUL_PORT:8500}
  config:
    enabled: ${CONSUL_ENABLE:true}
    prefix: ${CONSUL_CONFIG:config}
    fail-fast: true
    data-key: application.yaml
    name: ${spring.application.name}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)`

Answer (score -1):

Add it to

@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false", "spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=false"})

or
test/resources/bootstrap.yml as

spring.cloud.consul.enabled: false
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled: false